# If $f'(x)=g(x)$ and $g'(x)= -f(x)$ for all $x$ and $f(2)=4=f'(2)$. Find value of $f^2(4) +g^2(4)$

Tags: derivatives

**Problem**:If $f'(x)=g(x)$ and $g'(x)= -f(x)$ for all $x$ and $f(2)=4=f'(2)$. Find value of $f^2(4) +g^2(4)$

**Solution**:

I tried this question by first principle method of derivative but didn't get the answer

Comment: Hint: Try to build $f''(x)$. What can you conclude?

Comment: Can you show $f^2(x)+g^2(x)$ is constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT : use the fact that $\frac{d}{dx}(f^2) = 2f'(x)f(x)$

Using those you can prove that the expression $f^2(x) + g^2(x)$ is constant, this is conservation of energy in the physical system.

Comment: then  $f^2(4) + g^2(4) = f^2(2) + g^2(2)$

Comment: Yes, it's a constant. The idea is to this values does not change with respect to the variable. But you need to show it's a constant using my hint first.

Comment: Then ans is $32$ .it is constant as derivative of $f^2(x) + g^2(x)$ is $0$. Am I right ?

Comment: Exact. That's the quickest I see to solve it. You find the solution for $f$ and $g$ which is $\cos$ and $\sin$, reason why $f^2 + g^2 = cst$. But that takes longer...